# xcode iphone app problem with app not closing on ad click

Tags: iphone, c++, xcode, cocoa-touch, mobile

I have a webview inside mainwindow.xib. Te webview shows an admob ad and when clicked it is supposed to close the app and open the app store. For some reason this is not happening. When the ad is clicked nothing happens. Can this be due to the webview being inside main instead of a viewcontroller? If not then what can be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that some other view is intercepting the touches, the UIWebView has user interaction disabled, or the view the UIWebView is a child of has user interaction disabled.

It's hard to say exactly without some more information. Can you take a screenshot of how the mainwindow.xib is laid out?

Comment: The webview is inside a window which is inside the mainwindow.xlb. Then I also have a imagepicker view inside a seperate viewcontroller. I am able to click the ad and everything else in the webview however it seems the function that is supposed to close the app abd launch the appstore is not working

Comment: Hmm, since you can tap the ad, touch must be working. I'm guessing all it's doing is using a URL starting with itms:// to launch the app store. I'm not sure why that's not working, I wish I could help more. You may want to try placing the UIWebView in a view controller though to see if that makes any difference.